# react hook form setValue of fieldArray not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm currently facing an issue with react hook form while trying to update field Array value.

```
 const articlesFieldArray = useFieldArray({
   control,
   name: "articles",
 });
```

the issue is

- when trying to update the value using **setValue** its working as expected only for the first time , (default value is "[]" )

```
//this is working as expected
setValue("articles", [{articleId: 1,  price: 100, qte: 10 }])
```

-after updating values from input (for example updating price to "120") and calling setValue the values are updated is rhf state but not in the ui

**sandbox:** "https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-breeze-z48pyr?file=/src/App.js"

Comment: Need to see the rest of the code …  and also fix how you are presenting the sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> calling setValue the values are updated is rhf state but not in the ui

The problem you're experiencing with updating the UI's new value is because of how you set the `key` element in the `Box` component. In your example, you've set it to the array element `index`. React Hook Form produces internal field IDs for tracking the field array element; therefore, you must use `field.id` as the `Box` `key` prop.

```
{articlesFieldArray.fields.map((field) => <Box key={field.id}>...</Box>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reset({articles, [{articleId: 1,  price: 100, qte: 10 }]}). You can't achive this using setValue as setValue don't accept key.

https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/2429